# Difference between MySQL Range partitioning RANGE TO_DAY(DtCol) vs RANGE COLUMN(DtCol)

Tags: mysql, date-range, database-partitioning

I would like to understand, if there is any difference between RANGE TO_DAY(DateCol) and RANGE COLUMN(DateCol) MySQL RANGE partitioning by Dates.

MySQL Version : 5.7.12

**Sample test scripts:**

```
CREATE TABLE log_tbl_1 (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  stime datetime not NULL,
  primary KEY id (id, stime)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
  PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS( stime ) (
    PARTITION p20180401 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-04-02'),
    PARTITION p20180402 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-04-03'),
    PARTITION p20180403 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-04-04'),
    PARTITION p20180404 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-04-05'),
    PARTITION p20180405 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-04-06'),
    PARTITION p20180406 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-04-07')
    );

 CREATE TABLE log_tbl_2 (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  stime datetime not NULL,
  primary KEY id (id, stime)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
  PARTITION BY RANGE(to_days(stime)) (
    PARTITION t20180401 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2018-04-02')),
    PARTITION t20180402 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2018-04-03')),
    PARTITION t20180403 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2018-04-04')),
    PARTITION t20180404 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2018-04-05')),
    PARTITION t20180405 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2018-04-06')),
    PARTITION t20180406 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2018-04-07'))
    );
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: They are the same.. "Partitioning schemes based on time intervals.  If you wish to implement a partitioning scheme based on ranges or intervals of time in MySQL 5.7, you have two options: " "1 Partition the table by RANGE, and for the partitioning expression, employ a function operating on a DATE, TIME, or DATETIME column and returning an integer value" "2 Partition the table by RANGE COLUMNS, using a DATE or DATETIME column as the partitioning column" -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-range.html

Comment: The only difference is that RANGE COLUMNS won't require a function that convert a DATE, TIME, or DATETIME into a integer making the SQL eazier to read and maybe also eazier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks a lot Raymond Nijland :)